# Cannot access my database, it says database inaccessible

Tags: sql-server, database

I am hositng my application on a server but runs my Sql server in windows mode as application is still bieng developed. But suddenly when today I opened my Sql Management Studio, it is not allowing me access to my database although it was fine yesterday when I stopped working. It says Database is inaccessible and also the other databases that where there are not showon in the object explorer. I tried running report query to see my login report but it says you don't have permission to perform this action. Yesterday I didn't made any database related changes to my application also, I don't know what went wrong. Although my application is still getting data from the database but I am not able to access the database from Sql Management Studio. Can anybody please help me by telling what might have went wrong or what is the cause of this thing. What Should I do? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are there any errors? Can you post a screenshot of Object Explorer? Are you sure you are connected to the correct instance of SQL Server?

Comment: Yes I am sure that I am connected to the correct instance and there are no errors, its just saying that The Database MYDB is not accessible(ObjectExplorer). I am working on the same database since 3 months and opened the database today morning as usuall and its not allowing me in niether its showing my other databases.

Comment: Try restarting management studio. If that doesn't work I'll need a screenshot to see what's going on.

Comment: Something is wrong with your connection if you're not even able to see other databases you could see before.  This could be caused by a lot of different things, though, so you'll have to post more information about errors you're receiving.  It could be a disabled login, it could be network configuration, it could be your PC's network connection, ...

Comment: Is there a possibility that something might have went wrong on the sever side where I am hosting my data? Acutally I am hosting my data on other department's server, so is there a possibility that something went wrong there that's why I am not able to access anything because at my end everything was fine till yesterdat when I went home.

Comment: Yes, it's very much a possibility.  They could have changed SQL Server's network configuration.  If there's a router or firewall in between your PC and the server then something could have changed there that is blocking your connection, all kinds of things.  Give them a call and see if they can look into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to log in but not see databases, I suspect that someone has made changes to your account (reduced your permissions).  You're going to have to call the other department you mentioned and ask them to look into it for you.

(I assume you and the application were using different accounts.  If not, they probably decided that your permissions were a security risk when run as the application.)